# Iterating over an array in IE8 with Angular.js and ng-repeat includes an extra element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I've just begun building my first Angular app and need to support IE8. I just checked out IE8 after some quick prototyping and I've run into my first issue which seems too simple a task for there to be problems already. But it is IE8. Anyway I'm just doing a simple `ng-repeat` over an array of objects with 3 items in it, but IE8 renders a 4th item with no content in it.

Here's part of my JSON:

```
"members": [
  {
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "last_name": "G",
    "initials": "JG",
    "email": "jack@g.com",
    "manager": true
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Guy",
    "last_name": "One",
    "initials": "GO",
    "email": "guy@one.com",
    "manager": false
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Guy",
    "last_name": "Two",
    "initials": "GT",
    "email": "joe@g.com",
    "manager": true
  },
]
```

and my `ng-repeat` code:

```
  <div id="committee-members">
    <div class="committee-member" data-ng-repeat="member in members">
     {{member.initials}}
    </div>
    <span>
      <a class="edit-committee-members" data-ng-href="" title="">Edit</a>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks.

Comment: See the trailing comma in your array? IE 8 will add an undefined item to the end of the array. The length of the array would be `4`, even though you only think you have 3. This problem would happen too in other browsers, if you had more than one trailing comma. For example, in Chrome: `[,,,,]` has a length of `4`, and `[1,]` has a length of `1`

Comment: the "trailing comma" is just after the third item in your JSON data.

Comment: Ah, dumb mistake. That's interesting though, good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian you should put as answer to get credit...

Comment: @DanDoyon Thanks, but I would really think this question should be closed as the problem was a typo

Comment: @Ian actually, some people ignore IE and add trailing commas because other browsers support it. That's how i was looking at it. I did miss Jacks